# Как добавить с помощью js или jquery чтобы во время клика на ссылку изменяло цвет(добавлял и удалял класс visited)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

```css
.date{
    float:left;
    padding-top: 2.7%;
    padding-left:2%;
    width: 75%;
}

.date ul{
}

.date ul li{
    display: inline;
    margin-right:5%;
}

.date ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color:rgb(77, 76, 74);
    font-weight: bold;
}

.date ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color:rgb(77, 76, 74);
    font-weight: bold;
}


.date ul li a:hover{
    color:rgb(201, 121, 30);
}

.visited{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
        
        <div class="date">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Пн 18 Ноября</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Вт 19 Ноября</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ср 20 Ноября</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Чт 21 Ноября</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пт 22 Ноября</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Сб 23 Ноября</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Вс 24 Ноября</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Прочитайте про событие onclick

Comment: document.querySelector(".date a").onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector(".date a").classList.add('visited');
} - добавил это, но все равно не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('div.date ul').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    $(e.delegateTarget)
      .find('a')
      .each(function() {
        $(this).is(e.target) ? $(this).toggleClass('visited') : $(this).removeClass('visited');
      });
  });
});
```

Разница с предыдущим кодом, в том что по нажатию на текущую ссылку, класс тоглится

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('div.date ul').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    $(e.delegateTarget).find('a').removeClass('visited');
    $(this).addClass('visited');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.date {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 2.7%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  width: 75%;
}

.date ul {}

.date ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.date ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgb(77, 76, 74);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.date ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgb(77, 76, 74);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.date ul li a:hover {
  color: rgb(201, 121, 30);
}

.date ul li a.visited {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Пн 18 Ноября</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Вт 19 Ноября</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ср 20 Ноября</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Чт 21 Ноября</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пт 22 Ноября</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Сб 23 Ноября</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Вс 24 Ноября</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание, я в CSS изменил селектор с `.visited` на `.date ul li a.visited`. Иначе определение цвета в селекторе `.date ul li a` было более приоритетным

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Но мне еще нужно, чтоб при клике на другую ссылку у старой цвет вставал на старый

Comment: @verbtobe сделал как вам нужно

Comment: спасибо большое!!!